# iPhone application become so slow when it become active

Tags: iphone, ios5

i have a iPhone application which work with sql and web service , it loads data and work with it, it has good performance when i use it but when the app minimize and become active after a while the application is so slow , scrolling on tableview, navigation between views are so slow.

**i think it is not for data loading because whole application is slow not the views that have data or load data.**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Without more detailed explanation and code we cannot help you.

Comment: is it slow on the simulator or on the device?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to learn about the Instruments in xCode, is the kind of tool you should use when you have a problem like this, I dont think somebody is going to be able to tell you the solution to this problem.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652